# QtCore4.dll with QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, http, qnetworkaccessmanager

My project was perfetly running.

I was interested to send some requests with the QNetworkAccessManager. To do so, I have started with the first [example](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) and included

```
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
```

As soon as I include the following lines:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://qt.nokia.com")));
```

As soon as I write the first line (QNetworkAccess ...... ) and try to run, I am getting a new error which has shown up from the first time :

```
ENTRY POINT NOT FOUND
The procedure entry point ??0QDataStream@@QAE@PAVQByteArray@@H@Z could not be located in the dynamic link library QtCore4.dll (and respectively QtCored4.dll when I am switching to the debug mode).
```

Comment: Can you please fix the entry point name? I'm pretty sure it's different (and contains a lot of `@` symbols).

Comment: @peppe Please find above the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Did you include network in your pro file?

  CONFIG += core network
- Use an app like *Depency Walker* to check which dll will be loaded. Eventuall you have an older QtNetwork.dll installed in your system (evtl. $WIN$/system32/) which will be called at higher priority than your QtNetwork.dll in your QT-Directory/Development-Directory.
- Also check your path-variable and qt-environment variables.

If you find a wrong dll try to rename it and restart. Another option would be to do a full clean and qmake, but most probable reason will be a wrong .dll being loaded.